# Meteor -- bind click handler to button inside a conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor

I have a Meteor template with 2 possible HTML blocks, depending on a conditional: `already_facebook_authed`. As the code below shows, `already_facebook_authed` is the result of a Session variable, and that Session variable is asynchronously set. It seems like when the template is rendered, the Session variable (and thus `already_facebook_authed`) is falsey so when trying to bind a click handler to `#deauth_facebook_button`, it does not exist yet because it is in the other block which is not yet rendered.

How can I bind a click handler to `#deauth_facebook_button`? Perhaps there is some callback for when a certain DOM element is rendered in which I can instantiate this click handler?

---

```
------------
-- auth.html

<template name="accounts_auth_with_facebook">
  {{#if already_facebook_authed}}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="deauth_facebook_button" class="btn btn-primary"> Deauth Facebook </button>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="facebook_button"> Authenticate with FB </div>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>

----------
-- auth.js

Template.accounts_auth_with_facebook.rendered = function () {

  $('#facebook_button').unbind('click.auth').bind('click.auth', function() {
    // some handler code
  });

  $('#deauth_facebook_button').unbind('click.deauth').bind('click.deauth', function() {
    // some other handler code
  });
};

Template.accounts_auth_with_facebook.already_facebook_authed = function() {
  Meteor.call('get_composer_id', function (error, result) {
    if (blah blah blah) {
      Session.set('logged_in_with_facebook', true);
    }
  });
  return Session.get('logged_in_with_facebook');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use jQuery for setting up click handlers on Meteor templates, use the Meteor standard events mechanism :

```
Template.accounts_auth_with_facebook.events({
  "click #facebook_button":function(event,template){
    // some handler code
  }
  "click #deauth_facebook_button":function(event,template){
    // some other handler code
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked in a jiffy.